# Azure Logic App SQL Connector ODATA Filter on Date Column resulting empty output

Tags: odata, azure-sql-database, azure-logic-apps

I am creating a logic app which reads Data from Azure SQL Database Table. In ODATA filter I specified the condition to pick the records which have the date equal to '2017-06-16'(Column type: DATE). I am sure that the table I have created has such record. But when I executed the work flow the output is coming as empty. Can any one let me know how to write the condition here.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a custom object or a custom field on a standard object then the api name of the field should end with __c.

It could also be that Salesforce won't be expecting quotes around a date or datetime field.